# Multiply a css value that changes itself from time to time

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've got a image swiper for mobile visitors it's a full width swiper. It swipes itself every ten seconds of you don't slide it yourself normally the images have a width of max width of 640 px and the images are responsive to fit in the screen the slider goes to left or right left:"X"px; it checks what the width of your screen is and thats how far it goes left or right(left: negative or positive number). Now i have images that have a max-width of 1240px.

[image]

the red shows what where the slider has to go over. I can't change the script that does the slider so i had to figure out something else, I did and i came up with the idea to multiply the width by 2 so the slider goes 1280px to the left or right the css that goes to the left or right happens with left: "X"px;

I tried allot of jquery codes to do this it works kinda but the slider goes back to the standard left: if you come on the page the left is 0px; so it can't do anything then then it goes for example to 640px; and than it doesn't multiply it by 2. Now I tried it on an other element on a width and it just worked but thats because that value is not changing itself.

Now I was wondering is it possible to multiply the left every time his value changes.

Comment: can you please provide code / jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem of **OVERRIDING CSS** values by slider please use "`!Important`" with your pixels and then see

like `position-left:'1280px!important';`

I hope your problem will solved

Edit:

Jquery code will like

```
var currntLeft = $("#OR.Element").position().left;
var currntTop = $("#OR.Element").position().top;
```

and then do multiplication and set it again

```
currntTop = currntTop * 2;
currntLeft = currntLeft * 2;

$("#OR.Element").css('top',currntTop+'px!important');
$("#OR.Element").css('left',currntLeft+'px!important');
$("#OR.Element").css('position','absolute');
```

Comment: I need something like a jquery code that has to multply the left:

Comment: @Rikato I had updated my answer

Comment: i think it would work buut im a front-end dev and i dont know how to setup a function where i can put this i can you help with that?

Comment: You can put this function after your slider runs

Comment: I don't have acces to the slider.js but i have a custom.js so i have to make a function in custom.js if i put my id's and classes in the code and put it in the custom.js it doesn't work so ithink it needs to be a functio, but how ?